# I can't understand relationship between superclass, interface and child class if I use the same name methods in both interface and abstract class

Tags: java, oop, interface, overriding, abstract-class

```
public interface Pet { // Pet Interface
    default void introduce() {
        System.out.println("Interface");
    } 
}

abstract public class Animal {
    public void introduce() {
        System.out.println("Animal class");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal implements Pet{}
```

Now when I called the `introduce` method on `Dog`, what actually happens?

Comment: The implementation in Animal will be called. The one in the interface is a default, which means it's used if no other is available.

Comment: *"what actually happens?"* Why don't you **try it** and see for yourself?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default methods are always 'last in line'. If any method anywhere in the hierarchy of the chain of classes (so, here, 'Dog' at the top, then Animal, then Object - those are the classes involved in the hierarchy) matches, that always wins.

Only if zero methods are found in the entire class chain, and the interface chain contains exactly 1 method with a default implementation - then that one is chosen instead. If there are more than one, then your code won't compile (if you have `class A implements B, C {}` and both `B` and `C` have the same method defined and both have a default impl, then you can't compile A without explicitly writing that method into A.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense now.